# Comparing Floating Numbers From Text File

Tags: java

I created a text file with 15 random floating numbers and I'm trying to create a program which compares them all starting from the first until the last one.
I used the `if (stocksList.get(i) > stocksList.get(i+1))` for comparing and `scanner.nextDouble` to read them. 
My problem is when it's on the last two numbers it can't compares them because there's now 16th number so it gives an error due to using `i+1`. 
Is there a way to make the program stop on the 15th num so it won't give the error?

```
public static void main(String [] args)
throws IOException
{
int num, countUp, countDown, countSame;
num = 0;
countUp = 0;
countDown = 0;
countSame = 0;
FileInputStream stocks = new FileInputStream(args[0]);
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(stocks);
ArrayList<Double> stocksList = new ArrayList<Double>();
while (scanner.hasNextLine())
{
  stocksList.add(scanner.nextDouble());
}
//Dilbert's Rule
for(int i=0;i<stocksList.size(); i++)
{
  num++;
  System.out.printf(num + "%8.3f",stocksList.get(i));
  if(stocksList.get(i+1) > stocksList.get(i))
  {
  countUp++;
  }
  else if (stocksList.get(i+1) < stocksList.get(i))
  {
    countDown++;
  }
  else
  {
    countSame++;
  }
  if(countUp >= 3 && (countDown > 1 || countSame >= 1))
  {
    System.out.print(" " + "SELL");
    countUp = 0;
    countSame = 0;
  }
  else if (countDown >= 3 && (countUp > 1 || countSame >= 1))
  {
    System.out.print(" " + "BUY");
    countDown = 0;
    countSame = 0;
  }
System.out.println();
}
}
```

I made some MAJOR modifications since last time and now the only error i get is the `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. 
Plus If i but the `-1` on the `for` loop as many suggested it goes away but i lose my 15th line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a `stocksList.get(i+1)` whereas in your `for` loop you are checking `i<stocksList.size()`. This is bound to give you `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

For the last iteration of the loop, you will have `i` value to be `stockList.size()-1` and you want to access the location `i+1` which is `stockList.size()`. This would give you the exception.

You should check the condition `i<stocksList.size() - 1` in loop for the exception not to occur.

Comment: i know my fault am asking if there's a way to make it stop the program on the 15th line so it won't give me the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` error.
As I said the `i<stocksList.size() - 1` removes my 15th line

Comment: The last element can be accessed after the for loop manually. After the for loop, you can do whatever you want with the last element like: `System.out.println(stocksList.get(stocksList.size() - 1))`. Or inside the loop you can add a condition `if(i == stockList.size() - 1)` and do the required operation on the second last and last element.